# How do I make JSONDecoder parse this format? (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS)

Tags: json, swift, datetime, swift4

This is what I'm trying to decode:

```
{"MessageDate":"2017-11-28T05:04:40.9611765"}
```

I've omitted the rest of the JSON structure.

How do I have `JSONDecoder` parse that date format into a `Date` object?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
extension Formatter
{
    static let dotNetDateTime: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        return formatter
    }()

    /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/46458771/8462094
    static let dotNetDateTimeISO8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
        return formatter
    }()

    /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/46458771/8462094
    static let dotNetDateTimeISO8601NoMS: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX"
        return formatter
    }()

    static let dotNetDateTimeCustom: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS"
        return formatter
    }()

    static let iso8601Full: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXX"
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Some of those have been taken from other Stack Overflow posts.
I've also attempted a lot of other date decoding strategies not listed above.
I've scoured the internet for hours for solutions.
I've looked at the [Unicode documentation for date format patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
I've enlisted the help of another friend, and he doesn't know either.

I suspect the seven digit float at the end of the date string is the culprit, but I don't know how to tackle that.
Maybe I'm just missing something really small. Another set of eyes would be nice.

Any help is greatly appreciated guys, thanx.

I guess I should include the actual code where I'm parsing:

```
let attempt1 = JSONDecoder()
attempt1.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(Formatter.dotNetDateTime)
let attempt2 = JSONDecoder()
attempt2.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(Formatter.dotNetDateTimeISO8601)
//And more attempt initializations
...
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
if let deser = try? attempt1.decode(MessageThreads.self, from: data)
{
    return onDone(deser, nil)
}
if let deser = try? attempt2.decode(MessageThreads.self, from: data)
{
    return onDone(deser, nil)
}
//And more attempts
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. Sometimes when you need to debug, use Playgrounds.

```
extension Formatter
{
    static let dotNetDateTimeWithMilliseconds: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Just one `.S` will suffice to parse it.

Edit:
@Leo Dabus said I should include the locale, so I added it in. Thanx Leo for your help!

Comment: make sure to set your locale to en_US_POSIX. Another thing is are you sure the date  string coming from the server it is not UTC time?

Comment: Btw this will discard the rest of the fractional seconds also when parsing the date. If you are the one who is building  the API better to use a double and pass the timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate in your json

Comment: I don't really understand what the `en_US_POSIX` does. I know it forces the locale to the US, but what does that mean exactly? Do I want to force the locale if I _KNOW_ the server is based in the US? What if the server is in Europe or something, would I have to use a different locale? Also, if I keep adding S's like `.SSSSSSS` the rest of the fractional seconds is still discarded. (I'm not building the API (_but I really wish the api would use milliseconds since UNIX or something_))

Comment: The location of the server doesn't matter. en_US_POSIX it is required to parse your string properly

Comment: The maximum number of fractional seconds is 3 when parsing your date. the rest will be ignored

Comment: Again even without the time zone in your string it is probably UTC time.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is more useful to me than the unicode.org link I mentioned in my question.