# Data Corrupted ISO8601 Decodable Error Swift 4

Tags: swift, date, swift4, iso8601, codable

I have the following Swift code.

```
class Person: Codable {
    var born: Date
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
do {
    let person = try decoder.decode(Person.self, from: "{\"born\": \"2017-12-04T23:24:09.853Z\"}".data(using: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

I expect this to return a Person object with a `born` date of `2017-12-04T23:24:09.853Z` (which from what I can gather is a fully valid ISO8601 date).

Instead I get an error `dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [__lldb_expr_1.Person.(CodingKeys in _1Q81646826320N3Z86BD5V078M06H287).born], debugDescription: "Expected date string to be ISO8601-formatted.", underlyingError: nil))`.

According to Swift it looks like my date string is not `ISO8601-formatted` even tho I'm pretty confident it is (according to [this NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso8601-validator), and [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20012/online-tool-for-checking-iso8601)).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: An ISO8601 date will have the timezone as +/-XX:XX.

Comment: Awesome thanks @rmaddy, will have to restructure some things then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rmaddy Any reason why [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) would say my string is ISO-8601?

Comment: @rmaddy That's why I thought it was in ISO-8601 format. Before getting to my Swift code I run `.toISOString()` in Javascript and according to that link it should give me a ISO-8601 string.

Comment: @CharlieFish The problem it is not the Z it is the fraction seconds. Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458487/how-to-convert-a-date-string-with-optional-fractional-seconds-using-codable-in-s/46458771#46458771

Comment: You can check the expected  date format by creating a string representation of a Date using `ISO8601DateFormatter` method string(from: Date) which returns Z for UTC timezone `"2017-12-05T03:53:36Z"`

Comment: The problem is that if you  try to set the `formatOptions` property of the `ISO8601DateFormatter` to `[.withFractionalSeconds]` it will crash **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**. So you will need to create a custom date formatter to parse an ISO8601 date string if it contains fractional seconds.

Comment: @CharlieFish The best option is to use a `Double` `Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` instead of a string and set `dateDecodingStrategy` to `.deferredToDate`. `decode(Person.self, from: Data("{\"born\": 534139975.486094}".utf8))`