# My Swift code can not decode the JSON to structure

Tags: json, swift, struct

I have a page showing my user information and I want to give the user the ability to update the info . So I have created a update button and then if the user press that button it will send the info to API and get a json back as for the new values . My problem here is that I can not decode that json to my structure . 
Here is how I send my data :

```
     var user: Update?
    @IBAction func save_user_info_action(_ sender: UIButton) {
     var me = Me()
    let user_credentials = UserDefaults.standard
    guard let id = user_credentials.value(forKey: userDefaults_info.id.rawValue) else {return}


    let username = self.username_txt.text
    let fullname = self.fullName_txt.text
    let email = self.email_txt.text
    let sex = self.sex_txt.text
    let height = self.height_txt.text
    let weight = self.wight_txt.text
    let age = self.age_txt.text
    let password = self.password_txt.text

    if (username != "" && fullname != "" && email != "" && sex != "" && height != "" && weight != ""){

        let url = URL(string: "\(API.user_info_update.rawValue)\(id)")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        let postString = "user_name=\(username!)&email=\(email!)&password=\(password!)&sex=\(sex!)&height=\(height!)&weight=\(weight!)&age=\(age!)&full_name=\(fullname!)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in


            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("\(String(describing: response))")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print(responseString!)

            guard var result = responseString else { return }


            if let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Update.self, from: data){
               self.user = json

                print("username : \(self.user?.userID)")



            }

        }
        task.resume()
```

and as a result I get the following JSON ==>

```
{"user_id":13,"email":"jhx@gmail.com","password":"pass","user_name":"jhx","full_name":"no name","sex":"no sex","height":"0","weight":"0","age":"","score":0,"createdAt":"2017-12-10T05:18:42.000Z","updatedAt":"2017-12-11T05:36:58.000Z"}
```

and also here is my structure that I want to decode the json into ==>

```
import UIKit

struct Update: Codable { 


    let userID : Int?
    let email : String?
    let password : String?
    let userName : String?
    var fullName:String?
    var sex:String?
    var height:Int?
    var weight:Int?
    var age:Int?
    var score : Int?
    var createdAt:String?
    var updatedAt:String?



    func getUserID () -> Int {
        return self.userID!
    }
    func getScore () -> Int {
        return self.score!
    }


    func getEmail () -> String {
        return self.email!
    }
    func getPassword () -> String {
        return self.password!
    }

    func getUsername () -> String {
        return self.userName!
    }


    func getFullname () -> String {
        return self.fullName!
    }

    func getSex () -> String {
        return self.sex!
    }

    func getHeight () -> Int{
        return self.height!
    }

    func getWeight () -> Int{
        return self.weight!
    }



    func getCreatedAt () -> String {
        return self.createdAt!
    }




    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "user_id"
        case email
        case password
        case score
        case userName = "user_name"
        case fullName = "full_name"
        case sex
        case height
        case weight
        case age
        case createdAt
        case updatedAt
    }


}
```

but it doesnt work out . I've tried to debug it and it seems at the line that I have `if let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Update.self, from: data){` the program will never enter the if statement . Any idea where am I making a mistake ? and how can I fix it ? I am quite new to JSONs in swift ?

Comment: what is printing: print(responseString!) ?

Comment: Instead of declaring your structure properties variable, declare them as constants and create a new object with the new values if you need to change it.

Comment: I've used that to get the received json in my console once I can get result i can remove that

Comment: He asked what is the JSON response

Comment: `{"user_id":13,"email":"jhx@gmail.com","password":"pass","user_name":"jhx","full_name":"no name","sex":"no sex","height":"0","weight":"0","age":"","score":0,"createdAt":"2017-12-10T05:18:42.000Z","updatedAt":"2017-12-11T06:05:56.000Z"}`

Comment: SO like I said if your json have all properties of your user why do you need to change the existing one? Just create a new one. Btw sex should be a enumeration, not a string

Comment: @DanialKosarifa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458487/how-to-convert-a-date-string-with-optional-fractional-seconds-using-codable-in-s/46458771#46458771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the JSON, all strings are wrapped in double quotes so, `height`, `weight` and `age` are `String`, not `Int`.

This struct is sufficient. The functions are redundant if you declare all properties as non-optional

```
struct Update: Codable {

    enum Sex : Codable, String {
        case female, male, noSex = "no sex"
    }

    let userID: Int
    let email: String
    let password: String
    let userName: String
    let fullName: String
    let sex: Sex
    let height: String
    let weight: String
    let age: String
    let score: Int
    let createdAt: String
    let updatedAt: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "user_id"
        case email, password, score
        case userName = "user_name"
        case fullName = "full_name"
        case sex, height, weight, age, createdAt, updatedAt
    }
}
```