# Swift: Code builds but doesn't work—preview and simulator don't display desired result

Tags: swift, swiftui, preview

I can't seem to find any problems with my code, and it builds, but it doesn't show anything I've coded. I will attach my code for reference below. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

ArticleRowView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
fileprivate let relativeDateFormatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()

struct ArticleRowView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        List{
//        article: .previewData[0]
            ArticleRowView(article: .previewData[0])
                .listRowInsets(.init(top:0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }.listStyle(.plain)
    }
}

struct ArticleRowView: View {
    
    let article: Article
    
    struct Article {
        let site: String
        let title: String
        let date: Date
        let tickers: String
        let url: String
        let link: String?
        let author: String?
        let image: String?

        var siteText: String {
            site
        }
        var titleText: String {
            title
        }
        var tickerText: String {
            tickers
        }
        var dateText: String {
            "\(relativeDateFormatter.localizedString(for: date, relativeTo: Date()))"
        }
        var imageURL: URL? {
            guard let image = image else {
                return nil
            }
            return URL(string: image)
            
        }
    }
    struct NewsAPIResponse: Decodable {
        let content: [Article]
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            HStack(spacing: 16){
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4){
                    Text(article.siteText)
                        .font(Font.custom("Inter-Regular", size: 12))
                    Text(article.titleText)
                        .font(Font.custom("Inter-SemiBold", size: 15))
                        .frame(width: 247)
                        .padding([.bottom], 4)
                    HStack(spacing: 10){
                        Text(article.dateText)
                            .font(Font.custom("Inter-Regular", size: 12))
                        Image("rect")
                        Text(article.tickerText)
                        Image("green")
                            .padding([.leading, .trailing], -8)
                        Text("2.33%")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.345, green: 0.50, blue: 0.155, opacity: 1.0))
                    }
                    
                }
                AsyncImage(url: article.imageURL){
                    phase in
                    switch phase{
                    case .empty:
                        ProgressView()
                        
                    case .success(let image):
                        image
                            .resizable()
                    case .failure:
                        Image(systemName: "photo")
                        
                    @unknown default:
                        fatalError()
                    }
                }
            }
            Image("rect-hor")
        }
        
    }
}

extension ArticleRowView.Article: Codable{}
extension ArticleRowView.Article: Equatable{}
extension ArticleRowView.Article: Identifiable{
    var id: String{url}
}


extension ArticleRowView.Article {
    static var previewData: [ArticleRowView.Article] = { () -> [ArticleRowView.Article] in
        let previewDataURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "news", withExtension: "json")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: previewDataURL)

        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        jsonDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601

        let apiResponse = try!jsonDecoder.decode(ArticleRowView.NewsAPIResponse.self, from: data)
        return apiResponse.content ?? []
    }()
}
```

---

I have attached the news.json below for reference for endpoints.

news.json

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "title": "Core & Main, Inc Reports Strong Beat",
            "date": "2022-03-31 11:26:00",
            "content": "<p><a href='https://financialmodelingprep.com/financial-summary/CNM'>Core & Main, Inc. (NYSE:CNM) </a>reported its Q4 results, with EPS of $0.28 beating the consensus estimate of $0.22. Revenue was $1.25 billion, compared to the consensus estimate of $1.12 billion.</p>\n<p>The company unveiled its full 2022-year adjusted EBITDA guidance, which was well ahead of consensus estimates. The company expects Adj. EBITDA to range from $595 million to $635 million with an implied margin contraction of 80–90bp.</p>\n<p>Analysts at Berenberg Bank said they have limited visibility into how long the current hyperinflationary trends experienced in the company’s commodity-based products can persist and therefore acknowledge there could be an upside risk to their near-term estimates. Nonetheless, it is likely inevitable for these same commodity-based products to begin experiencing equally sharp deflationary pressures, resulting in more normalized margins and, by extension, muted medium-term EBITDA growth. Consequently, the analysts leave their $27 price target and Hold rating unchanged.</p>\n",
            "tickers": "NYSE:CNM",
            "image": "https://cdn.financialmodelingprep.com/images/fmp-1648740380438.jpg",
            "link": "https://financialmodelingprep.com/market-news/fmp-core-&-main-inc-reports-strong-beat",
            "author": "Davit Kirakosyan",
            "site": "Financial Modeling Prep"
        },
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": true,
            "unsorted": false,
            "empty": false
        },
        "pageSize": 5,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "offset": 0,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalPages": 161,
    "totalElements": 803,
    "last": false,
    "number": 0,
    "size": 5,
    "numberOfElements": 5,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false,
        "empty": false
    },
    "first": true,
    "empty": false
}
```

Comment: If you look in the preview diagnostics, you'll see an error "Expected date string to be ISO8601-formatted." If you fix that, it'll move on to an error about `url` not being present. These errors may continue. In short, your JSON doesn't match your model.

Comment: Hmm I don't seem to have any errors.

Comment: Click on diagnostics on the preview pane.

Comment: Do you know how to fix the ISO8601 error? I can't find the correct formatting.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343500/cant-decode-date-in-swift-4 for an example of how to set a custom DateFormatter when decoding