# Decode JSON response from API

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

I get some JSON objects from my api that look like this:

```
{
    "from": "1970-01-01",
    "until": null,
    "employeeId": "13",
    "project": {
        "id": "05c6adce-20cd-4ca3-9eff-8fd430f63a20",
        "version": 0,
        "name": "AGFA",
        "code": "AGFA",
        "start": "2016-01-01",
        "end": "2016-12-31",
        "alternativeCodes": []
    }
},
```

And I want to use the different parts of it in my program. I did some research and came up with this solution:

```
import SwiftUI
import CryptoKit

struct Project: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let version: Int
    let name: String
    let code: String
    let start: Date
    let end: Date
    let alternativeCode: [String]
}

struct AssignedProject: Decodable{
    let from: Date
    let until: Date
    let emloyeeId: Int
    let project: Project
}



struct FetchWebsiteView: View {
@Binding var apiKey : String
@State var assignedProjects = [AssignedProject]()
var body: some View {     
    VStack{
        
    }.onAppear{
        Task {
           var x = await doHTTPProjectsCall(token: apiKey)                                
        }
    }
}

func doHTTPProjectsCall(token:String) async -> Array<String> {
    let url = "http://localhost:8160/api/v1/project/assignments/13"
    guard let reqUrl = URL(string: url) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return(Array())
    }
    var req = URLRequest(url: reqUrl)
    req.httpMethod = "GET"
    req.setValue("CC0001", forHTTPHeaderField: "CC-Tenant")
    req.setValue("BE", forHTTPHeaderField: "CC-Product")
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601

            print("Program goes fine till here")

            if let decodedResponse = try?
                decoder.decode([AssignedProject].self, from: data) {

                print("Not doing this too")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.assignedProjects = decodedResponse
                    print("Not doing this")
                }
                return
                }
        } else if let error = error {
            print("HTTP Request Failed \(error)") // not printing any errors
        }
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("Response HTTP Status code: \(response.statusCode)") // but doing this fine and returning with status code 200 OK
            }
    }
    task.resume()
    
    
    return ["Internship", "Project2", "Test"]
}
}
```

Since it's not printing any errors and answering with status code 200 OK, i assume the request is fine but I have a problem decoding the JSON object. Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove that `try?` and use a proper do/catch block. But looking at your `AssignedProject` struct and your example JSON it seems there is an error with `until` property

Comment: Never use `try?` (with a question mark) unless you know how to debug. Use a proper `do`/`try`/`catch` and print the error thrown. Currently, you are just ignoring the parsing thrown error while it could tell you exactly why it failed the parsing...

Comment: @burnsi and Larme) thanks for the advice, i am going to try again and tell the results

Comment: @burnsi I fixed it and now it seems like it's working. The only problem left is like you mentioned that type error. Now I get following error: 
        "dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "from", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected date string to be ISO8601-formatted.", underlyingError: nil))"             any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You need to set a [date decoding strategy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895216-datedecodingstrategy) for your decoder. The date format used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343500/cant-decode-date-in-swift-4) is different but you should get a good idea on how to proceed from it.

Comment: Change the Dates to Strings, until should be optional.

Comment: I now see that you actually have one set already :), well you need a custom formatter for your date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot going on with the structs you try to decode to. You got several typos in here. E.g. `alternativeCode` instead of `alternativeCodes`...

Next there are several type mismatches here. For example `employeeId` is a `String` and not an `Int`.

Next the dates need a custom dateformatter to be decoded succesfully.

```
struct Project: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let version: Int
    let name: String
    let code: String
    let start: Date
    let end: Date
    let alternativeCodes: [String]
}

struct AssignedProject: Decodable{
    let from: Date
    let until: Date?
    let employeeId: String
    let project: Project
}


let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
let result = try decoder.decode([AssignedProject].self, from: data)
```