# How to decode a JSON array with no name?

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode

I am trying to decode a JSON from URL but my code can not decode this JSON.

This is the json: [image: json]

and this is my model object :

```
struct User: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let name: String
    let birthdate: Date
    let id: Int
}
```

and this is my fetch users code:

```
 func fetchUsers() async throws -> [User]? {
        let endPoint = EndPoint.users.rawValue
        guard let url = URL(string: endPoint) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return nil
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        do {
            let (json, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
            return try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: json)
         } catch {
             print(error)
         }
    }
    // create user with async/await
}
```

when I debug I get this data result of URLSession:
[image: json data]

Comment: Again check my last edit

Comment: Btw don't paste screen shots, paste your code/json string. Nobody will type it to test your code.

Comment: I have edited with your code but I am getting this error: Type 'Formatter' has no member 'iso8601'

Comment: Have you added the custom formatters I have posted below?

Comment: Please read the whole post throughly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue there is in your JSONDecoder dateDecodingStrategy. The default strategy is called `deferredToDate` which means it is expecting the `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`. What you need is a custom dateFormat to parse your ISO8601 date format. Check this [How to convert a date string with optional fractional seconds using Codable in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458487/how-to-convert-a-date-string-with-optional-fractional-seconds-using-codable-in-s/46458771#46458771).

Just create a custom DateFormatter iso8601 with and without fractional seconds:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let iso8601withFractionalSeconds: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        return formatter
    }()
    static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

And a custom dateDecodingStrategy:

```
extension JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy {
    static let customISO8601 = custom {
        let container = try $0.singleValueContainer()
        let string = try container.decode(String.self)
        if let date = Formatter.iso8601withFractionalSeconds.date(from: string) ?? Formatter.iso8601.date(from: string) {
            return date
        }
        throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Invalid date: \(string)")
    }
}
```

Now you can set your JSONDecoder dateDecodingStrategy properly:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .customISO8601
```

And use that decoder to parse your JSON string. Note that if you use try? you are discarding the error which you should use to debug your issue:

```
    return try decoder.decode([User].self, from: json) 
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I have implemented these extensions but it does not work,

Comment: I had to make some changes. Your date format doesnt have the timezone. Check my last edit. Make sure your date string time zone is UTC otherwise remove those lines `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` from the dateFormatters.

Comment: I implemented your code but I am receiving the error bellow : Type 'Formatter' has no member 'iso8601'

Comment: This means you haven’t added the necessary code to your project. Or you need to declare them as public.

Comment: right now it is working, but I get this error by the print inside the catch: valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 59", intValue: 59), CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: This means your name property should be optional String. Again add your JSON response string to your post. Please don’t add the answer code to your question

Comment: Btw you only need once catch for multiple try

Comment: it is working so good, I am so thank with you.