Decoding ISO8601 Date with Fractional Seconds fails
I'm working on decoding JSON data in Swift and encountering an issue with date strings that have fractional seconds. I've defined a custom date decoding strategy to handle ISO8601 dates, but for date strings like "2012-05-29T23:58:58.770000", the decoded result is incorrectly returning "2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000". Here's the code snippet I'm using:
private lazy var decoder: JSONDecoder = {
    
    let aDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    aDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601WithFractionalSeconds
    return aDecoder
}()

extension Formatter {
  static var customISO8601DateFormatter: ISO8601DateFormatter = {
  let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
  formatter.formatOptions = [.withTimeZone]
  return formatter
}()


extension JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy {
  static var iso8601WithFractionalSeconds = custom { decoder in
  let dateStr = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)
  let customIsoFormatter = Formatter.customISO8601DateFormatter
  if let date = customIsoFormatter.date(from: dateStr) {
     return date
  }
  throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(
      DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath,
                                 debugDescription: "Invalid date"))
}

I suspect the issue lies with how I've configured the ISO8601DateFormatter or possibly with the date string format itself. The expected behavior is to correctly decode the date string with seconds. However, the actual output for the date "2012-05-29T23:58:58.770000" is "2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000".
Could someone help identify what I might be doing wrong and how to correctly decode ISO8601 dates with fractional seconds in Swift?

have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458487/how-to-convert-a-date-string-with-optional-fractional-seconds-using-codable-in-s?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C121.4842
