# Date format issue in codable not working with decoder

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, codable

I am working on iOS app, in which I want to call the service, for this I am using alamofire and it is really very helping me.

Now I am calling a webservice which returns me model that has codable implemented. But I have observe that it is unable to convert the Date coming from server.

SO after a lot of searching I am able to get the extension that will help me in converting the date with format. take a look at extension

```
   extension DateFormatter {
  static let iso8601Full: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    return formatter
  }()
}
```

and using this as :

```
let data = Data(json.utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601Full)
```

now take a look at the date format that is coming from server: **Date Str :  2018-12-04T17:10:15.833**

For me the Date format is ok and it should work but bashing my head into this matter from last day but still I do not know what is the fault. Please help me...

Comment: The format should be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` without the Zs. I don't see a time zone anywhere in your date string.

Comment: there are multiple format also, how to tackle those ?

Comment: Why would your service return multiple formats?

Comment: I do not know, but it has multiple format. like in one date object it has "0001-01-01T00:00:00"          On this date format i am getting exception

Comment: @SharartiKAKI You can use a `.custom` date strategy to attempt multiple formats — if one works, you return the value; if none work, you can `throw`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682626/swifts-jsondecoder-with-multiple-date-formats-in-a-json-string/44686851#44686851

Comment: That is great idea to handle this.