# Date format in Swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

how i can implement this date format 1st July,2021 17:00.My current code is

```
func changeFormat(_ toFormat: String,_ dateStr: Date?) -> String{
        let date = dateStr ?? Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = toFormat
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    
func covertStringToDate(_ date: String) -> Date {
        let isoDate = date

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!
        
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordinal Month-day Suffix Option for NSDateFormatter setDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283045/ordinal-month-day-suffix-option-for-nsdateformatter-setdateformat)

Comment: Why force such an odd date/time format on your users? Most people will not be used to seeing that format. For any dates/times you want to display to the user it is best to use date/time styles with a DateFormatter instead of hardcoding a specific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to convert any `Date` object to this format do this.

```
let date = Date()

//create the date format without the day
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale     = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM,yyyy HH:mm"
let dateWithoutDay = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

//get the day from the date
let dayFormatter = DateFormatter()
dayFormatter.locale     = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dayFormatter.dateFormat = "d"
let day = dayFormatter.string(from: date)

//create a number formatter to get st/nd/rd/th suffix
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
let dayWithSuffix = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:Int(day)!))
```

```
print("\(dayWithSuffix!) \(dateWithoutDay)") // --> 3rd September,2022 22:52
```

---

If u want to convert this type of date (`1st July,2021 17:00` ) to a `Date` object do this.

```
let dateString = "1st July,2021 17:00"
let dateSuffix = dateString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits).joined().prefix(2)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale     = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd'\(dateSuffix)' MMMM,yyyy HH:mm"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "1st July,2021 17:00")
print(date!) // ->> 2021-07-01 11:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: You should use the users own locale (`.current`) for this kind of date format so the month name is in the users preferred language

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use localisation support, try this template(playground):

```
import Foundation

//let locale = Locale(identifier: "ar")
//let locale = Locale(identifier: "en-us")
let locale = Locale(identifier: "ja")

let dayOfMonth: NSNumber = 11
let dayPlaceholder = "dd"
let dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(
    fromTemplate: "\(dayPlaceholder)MMMM",
    options: 0,
    locale: locale
)

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = locale
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
let dayOrdinalString = numberFormatter.string(from: dayOfMonth)

let ordinalDateFormat = dateFormat?.replacingOccurrences(
    of: dayPlaceholder,
    with: "'\(dayOrdinalString ?? "")'"
)

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = locale
formatter.dateFormat = ordinalDateFormat
formatter.string(from: Date())
```

Comment: While an interesting approach, it will fail for some locales. The `dd` gets changed to just `d` in several locales.

Comment: @HangarRash yeah, maybe, anyway thats fixable.